# Multiplying a field by a constant

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am well aware that Q(a)(b) = Q(a, b). But, what if we have something like [Q(a)] (b)? There is a clear separation from Q(a) and (b)

It seems like b acts as a constant in this situation, rather than being "joined" in the situation above.

My question is: Does this describe the multiplication of a field with a constant? If so, how does one approach this?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I see, $\;\Bbb Q(a)(b)=\left[\Bbb Q(a)\right](b)\;$ . They're exactly the same: the field of rational functions in $\;b\;$ with coefficients from the field $\;\Bbb Q(a)\;$ , which is the field of rational functions in $\;a\;$ with coefficietns in the rational field. It is not, in any case, the multiplication of a field by a constant...whatever that could be.

Comment: No. It is just a simple way to signify that $Q(a)(b)$ is the field of all rational expressions of $b$ with coefficients in $Q(a)$. The fact that this is equal to $Q(a,b)$, which is the field of all rational expressions of $a$ and $b$ with coefficients in $Q$ is not trivial.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I don't see what is non-trivial. The field of rational expressions in something is the same as the smallest field containing the base field *and* the something. This *and* is clearly commutative and associative

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I almost agree with user1952009, and I'd say: it is not trivial...but very close to be.

Comment: Do you maybe mean $Q(a) b$, i.e., $\{ x b \;|\; x \in Q(a)\}$? That describes 'multiplication of the (base) field with a constant (from the extension field)'. It occurs in contexts like $Q(a,b) = Q(a) + Q(a)b + Q(a)b^2 + \dots + Q(a)b^{n-1}$, i.e., seeing $Q(a,b)$ as an $n$-dimensional $Q(a)$-vectorspace with basis $1, b, \dots, b^{n-1}$.